# Изменить регулярку для поиска не только латинских но и рф ссылок

Tags: регулярные-выражения, android, java, ссылки

Помогите пожалуйста изменить метод, чтоб он искал в строке не только ссылки латинского алфавита,а так же и ***.рф***.
 И ещё этот метод не ищет ссылку если она такого вида: *site.ru* , то есть сокращенная (без http или www) можно ли то исправить?

вот сам метод

```
ArrayList retrieveLinks(String text) {
    ArrayList links = new ArrayList();

    String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|https://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while(m.find()) {
    String urlStr = m.group();
    char[] stringArray1 = urlStr.toCharArray();

    if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")"))
    {

        char[] stringArray = urlStr.toCharArray();

        char[] newArray = new char[stringArray.length-2];
        System.arraycopy(stringArray, 1, newArray, 0, stringArray.length-2);
        urlStr = new String(newArray);
       // System.out.println("Finally Url ="+newArray.toString());

    }
    //System.out.println("...Url..."+urlStr);
    links.add(urlStr);
    }
    return links;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй такой, вроде работает:

String regex = "\(?\b([http://|https://|www[.])[\p](http://|https://|www[.])[%5Cp){L}+&@#/%?=~*()|!:,.;]*[\p{L}0-9+&@#/%=~*()|]";

Вот подробней:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204569/javas-regular-expression-dont-recognize-characters-from-other-languages-as-wor

Comment: не сработало.правда я еще экранировал слеши,может это повлияло
String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|https://|www[.])[\\p{L}+&@#/%?=~()|!:,.;]*[\\p{L}0-9+&@#/%=~()|]";

Comment: Ну не знаю, я взял твою программу, подправил капельку, как там в ссылке было написано, вбил в eclipse в простой пустой проект java 1.6, дал туда строку с линками вроде http://усипуси.рф и оно сработало. Может что-то с кодировкой текста не то? Нужно utf-16. Могу сюда прям всю программу залить, но там правда я ничего кроме A-Z на \\p{L} не менял. Слеши кстати двойные, просто их почему-то форматирует, когда я постю.

Comment: а да, это работает.извиняюсь. я имел ввиду ссылку типа site.ru/blablabla уже не распознаёт.только если http есть вначале